# Getting latitude and longitude from a servlet request in JSON and print out in a google map object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps, servlets

I'm trying to show in a page a google page with several markers on it. This is the workflow. When the page is loaded it call the following jquery function

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map_canvas");

    $.ajax('info', {

        type:"GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(list){

            if(list.length)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) 
                {
                    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(list[i].latitude,list[i].longitude);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latLng,
                        map: map
                    });
                }    
            }

            var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 2,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(list[0].latitude,list[0].longitude),
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
                    };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);   
        }

    });

 });
```

This will pass the request to the servlet mapped as `info`.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException 
{

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Airport.class, new AirportSerializer()).create();

    List<Airport> list = airportFacade.findAll();

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    response.getWriter().print(gson.toJson(list));

    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/view/generalinfo/airports.jsp").forward(request, response); 

}
```

I'm totally sure that the object `list` is full and formatted correctly in json style because when I try to make the request I get the page not with the map but with the json list printed out. The problem is I wrong to pass the list back correctly to the callback function in the way it could print the list

The problem is: how can I pass the json list to jsp page?

Comment: I didn't understand your question correctly. I'll remove my answer because it doesn't resolve your problem but just correct one error.

Answer (score 1):

To each request to your Servlet you may only respond once. So the question is, do you want to respond with JSON or by forwarding to the JSP? You can't do both.

From the code in your question it looks like you are handling the response on the page. Why do you need to forward to another jsp?

Just take out this line:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/view/generalinfo/airports.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

You should also flush the PrintWriter:

```
response.getWriter().flush();
```